# Javascript using DOMContentLoaded as multiple html files needed

Tags: javascript, html, readystate, domcontentloaded

I have some javascript that runs nicely when added to the end of a HTML file. However, I need the same script on multiple html files so attempting to add it to js file. All the links are fine as I already have other functions added. The documentation recommends using DOMContentLoaded along with a readystate function. It prints the first console.log and 'print loading' from if statement, and then stops. Can someone please help?

```
function addbutton(){
    let cartbutton = document.getElementsByName('ropebutton');
    console.log(cartbutton) // prints node []
    const cart = [];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < cartbutton.length; i++) {
        let button = cartbutton[i];
        console.log(button);
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            console.clear();
            console.log(event.target);
            console.log(event.target.dataset.test);
            cart.push(event.target.dataset.test);
            console.log(cart)            
        });
    }
}

if (document.readyState === 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addbutton);
    console.log("print loading");
} else {
    addbutton();
    console.log("print loaded");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `DOMContentLoaded` instead of using `defer`?

Comment: ...and to add I am attempting to add items to a variable when buttons are clicked.

Comment: documentation recommended, along with other posts on here. Is defer better?

Comment: yes because then you can use global variables directly and reuse parts of the script with other script files

Comment: I've removed the DOMContentLoaded and readystate. I've added defer to the script tag as suggested but I'm getting the same result. Works perfectly when at the bottom of HTML file but not in JS file. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the `defer` attribute to the style tag `<script src="URL" defer></script>` then you still load the script async'ed but the script will wait to be executed after all DOMContent is loaded.

Comment: There is no script tag. It's running from js file.

Comment: and how do you link the JS file so that it is run in the first place?

Comment: Of course it was on my layout page...
<script src="/static/ajax.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
However, still doesn't work.

Comment: I've removed the DOMContentLoaded and readystate. I've added defer to the script tag as suggested but I'm getting the same result. Works perfectly when at the bottom of HTML file but not in JS file. Thank you so far. Any further suggestions?